# How can I prevent a thief stealing my loot In Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I play on a server on minecraft ps4 edition (I call multiplayer games servers) . I havent been the target of a thief yet but how can I prevent it when the time comes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are a few precautions you can take, but I **strongly** recommend looking elsewhere as there are a lot of tips.

-HIDE YOUR BASE UNDERGROUND. It will be a lot harder to find that way, but make sure your entrance is well secure. You could hide the entrance under a floor, for example.

-DON'T USE CHESTS. If you're that concerned about losing your stuff, use dispensers and other storage units. It might not let you fit a lot of stuff inside, but hackers who can only see chests will not spot your base. You can also use minecart chests, but chances are those same hackers will also have those on to look for mineshafts.

-MAKE A DECOY BASE NEAR YOURS. If thieves are in the area and find the decoy, chances are they won't look much further in that area. Just make sure to fill the chests in the decoy with some items, or they might suspect something.

-BUILD TRAPS. You can find hundreds of survival compatible traps online.

-STUFF YOUR INVENTORY WITH YOUR STUFF EVERY TIME YOU LEAVE. Thieves can't steal what isn't there, after all.

-ENDER CHESTS are definitely one of the safest ways to keep your stuff safe.

Like I said, there are hundreds of sources online, so I recommend not asking a question on this site if there are already plenty of sources out there, unless none of them where what you needed (which you did not specify).

Comment: Let's add the Ender Chest. Ender chest filled with shulker boxes. All your possessions always on you. And even if you lose it, just find an ender chest in another player's base, and recover a brand new ender chest from one of your shulker boxes :)

Comment: @SF good idea, I'll add that.